# SavedModel file does not exist error while converting vgg16

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I want to convert **rcmalli_vggface_tf_vgg16.h5** pre-trained model to js format to use in a tensorflow-js project.

to convert this file I tried different ways but yet I could not to solve the problem.

I'm using `converters.convert_tf_saved_model` method to load and then convert it to a json file.

```
converters.convert_tf_saved_model('rcmalli_vggface_tf_vgg16.h5','web_model')
```

But every time following error is shown:

```
SavedModel file does not exist at: rcmalli_vggface_tf_vgg16.h5
```

While I am sure the h5 file is next to the file that is running the program.

I try full path address but same error occured. I do not know what is problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting a keras *saved_model* but the model is a keras *layers_model* because it is stored in h5 file.

I find this way the simplest to convert the model. And it did it in about 2 seconds.

1. Go to [TensorflowJS converter Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter)
2. Follow installation instructions
3. Download the model you point to [from the Github repo](https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface/releases/tag/v2.0).

   - The model is written in the HDF5 file format
   - By the way, this is the oldest of the models, why not to download a new one ?
   - Also, this is a huge model, unless runs on the server it is of no use for a browser (produces 50 shard files of 4MB.)
4. Perform the conversion*

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=keras rcmalli_vggface_tf_vgg16.h5 ./converted
```

5. The output will then be a layers model, and this has to be loaded with the [`tf.loadLayers` API.](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/4.2.0/#loadLayersModel)
6. For example, use `const model = await tf.loadGraphModel('path/to/model.json');`

Note*: `./converted` is the output directory, be sure not to overwrite your own stuff.